# What is this last number on a http GET request?

Tags: http, url, get

[image: The Last number]

What does the last number (5731) mean on this get request? I understand the other things, but I don't even know the term to google it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you copying this from?

Comment: @Sergey the terminal screen after modifying the website's uri

Comment: So you're in Linux/Unix? Some context on what you're doing would be very helpful. Is this some sort of program? Details details please.

Comment: Sorry, I really appreciate the help even though I've been less than helpful. Anyway, it is from the apache return message from a localhost version of a website that I'm maintaining. I've been seeing what happens when I change the numerical argument (2550) and naturally, it takes me to a different page. However, each time the I pages change, the number on the end also changes. I know it is not the http status code as that is the number before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the "content-length" of the response, meaning the 'size in bytes' of the body that was returned as a response to this request.

If you want to confirm that that's the case, try requesting a URL and copying the HTML content (or whatever is returned, maybe JSON...) of the page into a text editor that can tell you the number of characters in the document. If the number at the end of the request (e.g. 5371 as in the screenshot) matches the number of characters in the document, then that number is "content-length"

Answer (score 0):

The meaning depends on your log format for your configuration; for a common log format:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

the two numbers in your example are:

200 (%>s)

> This is the status code that the server sends back to the
>
> > client. This information is very valuable, because it reveals whether
> > the request resulted in a successful response (codes beginning in 2),
> > a redirection (codes beginning in 3), an error caused by the client
> > (codes beginning in 4), or an error in the server (codes beginning in
> > 5). The full list of possible status codes can be found in the HTTP
> > specification (RFC2616 section 10).

***> 2326 (%b) The last number indicates

> the size of the object returned to the client, not including the
> response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value
> will be "-". To log "0" for no content, use %B instead.***

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#combined